# Apply strip() to all cells in dataframe with multiple data types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has multiple data types. Part of my processing code is to apply the `strip()` function before I work on the df.

My example df:

```
Unnamed: 1      Unnamed: 2      Unnamed: 3  Unamed: 4
Protocol Number NaN             NaN         5
xyz-4134        NaN             3           NaN
Section FINANCE Cost Category   Major Tasks # of Units 
NaN             1325            some string NaN
```

Here is my code:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) == str else x)
```

It doesn't seem to be processing for all strings though. I'm still seeing spaces before and after in some of my output cells.

## Question

Is there a better way to apply `strip()` to my entire raw dataframe? In the above input dataframe, the `# of Units`  has a trailing white space and the  `some string` has a leading white space

Comment: Can you share sample of that part of df where your lambda doesn't do stripping?

Comment: @Firelord I've added a sample df. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `applymap` doesn't do inplace replacements, so try `df = df.applymap(...`

Comment: You should use `isinstance(x, str)` instead of `type(x)==str` when checking if element is string.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly awesome, I didn't realize that. Looks like it works on pure strings now. But for some reason the `# of Units ` with trailing space is still sticking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating the suggestions by both IgnatiusReilly & Rabinzel, this worked for me:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Also worth noting, the reason the `# of Units` was keeping the trailing space was because I used used `applymap` after I already assigned that row as the headers. I moved the cleaning before the header assignment and it worked.