# Inferring datetime64[ns] from data containing strings is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, pandas

I find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73514969/19442010) a way to apply `.strip()` to all cells in dataframe with multiple data types and thus remove all white space in my dataframe.

```
file = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')  

def remove_whitespace( x ):
    if isinstance( x, str ):
        return x.strip()
    else:
        return x

my_data = file.applymap( remove_whitespace )
```

but I get this message, and I don't know/understand how to adapt the code

> FutureWarning: Inferring datetime64[ns] from data containing strings is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To retain the old behavior explicitly pass Series(data, dtype=datetime64[ns])
> my_data = fichier_source.applymap( remove_whitespace )

Comment: What is the data in the file?

Comment: @Guy I hope I haven't misunderstood the question. The type are  float, int, str, numpy.float64 and timestamps.Timestamp